# "setOnClickListener" methode doesn't work on custom layout file set by "setContentView"

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

## OnClickListener does not work on custom imported views using "setContentView"

The android app has activity and its activit_layout. Then I placed three button on activity_layout and set "onclicklistener" for each buttons in order to open different custom views. Each button set specific layout file for the activity using "setContentView" methode inside "onclicklistener" methode and they work well. Then, those each custom layouts have sperate textview on them. Once agian, I want set "setOnClickListener" for these each textviews that are on custom layout files, seperatelty and perform different tasks. Thing is when I click on the textview, nothing happens at all. I have no idea about weather text is recognized or "onclicklistener" methode doesn't work.
Here I'm attaching my code file below.

Activity java file :-

```
public class beverbs extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private int layout = 0; // interger for custom layout file
    TextView text1;  // textview is on the custom layoutfile
    View view1;   // custom Layout file

    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);


        view1 = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext()).inflate(R.layout.custome_layout,null);

        text1 = view1.findViewById(R.id.textView12);

        text1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()   // this part does not work
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                // do something
            }
        });

    }

    public void open_new_layout(View view)  // onclick methode  
    {
        layout = 1;
        setContentView(R.layout.custome_layout);  // button on main layout set  custom layout the activity 
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        if (layout==1)
        {
            layout = 0;
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);  // set original layout again
        }
        else
        {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

Activity XML file :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="open_new_layout"
        android:text="Open Layout"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Custom layout XML file:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Perform Task"
        android:textSize="34sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Pls anyone help me with this weather there's another way to do my task.

I dug the internet for any solution but got nothing regarding with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're inflating a layout (`custome_layout.xml`) and setting a click listener on its `TextView`, but you're not actually displaying that inflated layout - so the user can't click on it!

I'm guessing you actually want to set the click listener on the `Button` in `activity_layout`:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // inflate and display the main activity layout
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);

    // find the button on the displayed layout
    Button button = findViewById(R.id.button5);
    
    // set a click listener on it
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // call openNewLayout or whatever
        }
    };
}
```

---

A problem here is you're using `setContentView` with layout resource IDs, like `setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout)`. That takes the XML file, *inflates* its layout (i.e. creates the `View` objects described in the XML file and connects them up), and finally displays that final hierarchy of `View` objects.

When you find `button` and set a click listener on it, *you're setting it on that specific `View` object*. If you call `setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout)` again (like in your 'back' function) then *it inflates a new set of `View` objects*. The `Button` with the `button5` ID **won't have a click listener set on it** until you set it up again, because it's a completely new object.

---

You have two options here. You can manually inflate each view hierarchy and store them (like you're doing with `R.layout.custome_layout` in `onCreate`) and then call `setContentView(view1)` etc, i.e. passing *a set of `Views` for display*. That way, since you're using the same objects, any click listeners will still be set.

The other option is to do what you're doing, and call `setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout)`, but run your setup code (adding click listeners etc) every time you call it - you're inflating new objects, so you need to set them up every time. The easiest way to do that would be creating a method like `showMainLayout()` that has the `setContentView` and `setOnClickListener` code, and call that when you want to display that layout.

Or you could use `Fragment`s and just swap between those - this kind of thing is a big part of what they're for.

Comment: "setOnClickListener" works well on the button with ID "button5" on the activity's original layout even after going back again (like in the "onBackPressed()" method).  The problem is with the "setOnClickListener" on text-view on the newly inflated layout file using the "setContentView" method. In my activity code, I have set the "onClick" attribute to the button with ID "button5" and its method is in the activity code as "public void open_new_layout(View view)". When I click on that, it displays the inflated layout correctly. Every time , no matter what "button5" works well.

Comment: @IsuruThiwanka oh right, you're setting one of your click listeners in XML, I didn't notice that - sorry! The rest still stands though - you need to set your click listener on the view hierarchy being displayed, and when you call `setContentView(R.layout.some_layout)` you're inflating *a new set of Views for display* .So your click listener won't work, because the View object you added it to isn't on the screen. You need to add a click listener to the new View, or use `setContentView` with your already inflated hiearchy, like I explained in the answer

Comment: Yes. I did what you said. It worked..Thanks lot

Answer (score 0):

Solution : Here we need to store customer layouts in "View" objects in "oncreate()" method. Then set new layout using "setContentView()" method like

```
setContentView(view);
```

Then initiate a child object on the view like `textview = view.findViewById(R.id.id_of_element);`

then set the "setOnClickListener" on that element ..
It works..